# Configure an Apache rewrite-rule to redirect 404 requests to a html file

Tags: apache

I do have a requirement to rewrite all my 404 error pages to a html file. I tried with

```
ErrorDocument htdocs/error.html
```

But the pages are not getting redirected to it in case of no pages.
I am using Apache to get data from JBOSS using Mod-JK.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess in the htdocs folder.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

Comment: Did we need to give any entries in htaccess

Comment: I have created .htaccess and still i have the issue.

Comment: Ok and you have the exact text i posted + the error.html file in that folder correct?

Comment: Ya actually it seems here is some wrong configuration on the server corresponding to Jboss. Now I have setup a same environiment and on that it is working fine. Need to debug the issue and I will take care of it.

Thanks for your help.

Regards, Sriharsha Kalluru.